# "Cannot find symbol - method add" using ArrayList

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I am trying to create a method that allows another `Account` to be added to a collection:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * The Account list if the grouping of all the accounts for customers in the system.
 * 
 * @author
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class AccountList
{
    // This is the ArrayList being declared

    private ArrayList<Account> accounts;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class AccountList
     */

    public AccountList()
    {
        //This is the ArrayList being initialised in a constructor.
        accounts = new ArrayList<Account>() ;
    }

    /**
     * This method will allow a new account to be added to the system.
     * 
     * @param accounts the accounts in the system.
     */
    public void addAccount(Account accounts)
    {
        accounts.add();

    }
}
```

The problem is that it cannot find the method `add` on the `addAccount` section even with the `ArrayList` class being imported at the top of the class. I'm new to Java so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't have an `add` method that doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: I think you encoutered the good old "Shadowing". Your `accounts.add()`operation is _NOT_ on your `accounts` field of the class, but on the methods parameter.

Answer (score 2):

change in code

```
public void addAccount(Account accounts)
{
    this.accounts.add(accounts);

}
```

for more [click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your `void addAccount(Account accounts)` method accepts a single parameter called `accounts` of type `Account`, and I'm assuming your `Account` class doesn't have an `add` method, so the error you got has nothing to do with `ArrayList`'s add method.

It should be :

```
public void addAccount(Account account)
{
    accounts.add(account);
}
```

Assuming you wish to add a single account to the account list.

Your mistake was using the same variable name `accounts` as argument for the method and as the member holding the list. The former hid the latter, and in addition, you didn't supply a parameter to the add method of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Change like below

```
public void addAccount(Account account)
{
    accounts.add(account);
}
```

If you use the local variable name same as outer variable. then local variable will be consider first.